# Barplot for several categorical variables divided by one categorical variable in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, lattice

I would like to visualize how a categorical variable varies for several other categorical variables.

My data looks like this

```
  Species Class species2
1   setosa     1        0
2   setosa     1        1
3   setosa     1        0
4   setosa     1        1
5   setosa     1        0
6   setosa     1        1
7   setosa     0        0
8   setosa     0        1
9   setosa     1        1
10  setosa     1        1
```

In my real `dataset` I have 13 categorical variables which I want to divide by class as follows.

[image: barchart]

Is there an easier way to do this with lattice, or other packages in `R`? Ideally I would like one plot with a panel for each variable, showing the counts or pecentages for each level, coloured by the variable 'class'.

For this example I used the following code.

```
library(lattice)
data <- iris
data <- as.data.frame(data)
data <- data[-c(1,2,3,4)]
data$Class <- as.factor(c(rbinom(50,1,0.7),rbinom(100,1,0.1)))
data$species2 <- as.factor(rbinom(150,1,0.85))

data2 <- as.data.frame(table(data$Species,data$Class))
barchart(Var1~Freq,groups=Var2,data=data2,stack=TRUE,
         auto.key=list(title = "Class",columns=2))
data3 <- as.data.frame(table(data$species2,data$Class))
barchart(Var1~Freq,groups=Var2,data=data3,stack=TRUE,
         auto.key=list(title = "Class",columns=2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this. I would suggest you to use `ggplot2`. The code described next can build a plot as you want for each variable. It is known as a feceted plot. The key to get it is to reshape data to long. Based on your code, you had to split according to each variable and then use `lattice` to create each plot separated. The advantage is that functions from `tidyverse` (`pivot_longer()`) allow you to transform data in a way that the plotting functions can be adjusted easily. Here the code that produces a plot for each variable. In your case, if you have more categorical variables, you can adjust the facets with `ncol` and `nrow` options. Next the solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
data <- iris
data <- as.data.frame(data)
data <- data[-c(1,2,3,4)]
data$Class <- as.factor(c(rbinom(50,1,0.7),rbinom(100,1,0.1)))
data$species2 <- as.factor(rbinom(150,1,0.85))
#Code
data %>% pivot_longer(-Class) %>%
  group_by(name,Class,value) %>%
  summarise(N=n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y=value,x=N,fill=Class))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',color='black',alpha=0.2)+
  facet_wrap(.~name,scales='free')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'top')
```

Output:

[image]

In the case of percentages, you can try this:

```
#Code 2
data %>% pivot_longer(-Class) %>%
  group_by(name,Class,value) %>%
  summarise(N=n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y=value,x=N,fill=Class))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',color='black',alpha=0.2,position = 'fill')+
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  facet_wrap(.~name,scales='free')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'top')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. Two quick questions however. Is there a nice way to get the same plot with percentages instead? And should I care about this 'error' message?  (summarise()` regrouping output by 'name', 'class' (override with `.groups` argument) )

Comment: @awend Sure, tell me!

Comment: @awend Second message is just a warning. So no worries. If you want percentages, let me add a solution for that. Just a moment please!